# PHP mail when inactive user

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

So I'm making a web system,
the idea is when a user closes the browser it will send an E-mail to me.
Currently the user is using Javascript Ajax to get PHP to update the database with the current time. When the time exceeds 5 mins then I want PHP to send me an E-mail. The database is setup for the users and stuff.

Could you please tell me if it's possible for the server to check every 30 seconds or so for the users to be active or not and send an E-mail if not. and If so could you give some examples of code and such of what I would need to do, currently I don't have access to the server as it's a DEV project at the moment and it's on a free webhosting service. I can move it onto a linux server that I have SSH access to if needed.

I do have a lot of knowlege on PHP but this completely beats me with a stick.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: You could write a `cron job` that executes a php script on your server every `x` minutes/seconds/etc

Comment: That's an idea. that would mean that I would SSH access to the server :/. I could setup the linux server and put the scripts on it and try. What would the cron job look like in crontab? for every 30 seconds execute a php script.
* * * * * 30 php /etc/script.php

Comment: An alternative to cron could be to run a script on every page load that will send the email for inactive users - the only big issue with that is it ALL users are inactive it will never be sent.  Cron is the best option, but I know that it's not possible with some hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible!

First, I would create a flag SENT which is set to false when the user logs in or each time the time is updated, depends on your app.

Then, you just need to setup a daemon (a.k.a cron) to run a php file each 30 seconds in which you compare the actual time to your users lastUpdateTime, when it is 5 minutes AND if the flag SENT is still false, it sends you an email and sets the user's flag to true so it doesn't keep sending you emails.

Comment: Like Patrick suggested, I have to setup the server, I can install everything but not sure when it comes to cron jobs.

Comment: I have only used the commands for cron jobs via UI, never commanded directly on a server so I wouldn't be able to help you with that :/

This might help you: http://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/ check number 11

Comment: Ok cheers, I'll get back to you when I finish setting up the server